# Estoy intentando crear roles en mi app de ASP.NET Core Y no se como hacer el builder en el program

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Estoy intentando hacer roles en mi app web pero no se por que no me lee los roles asignados,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi es donde creo las cookies.

segun lo que lei tengo que ir a a startup y a{adir una lineas de codigo para hacer el builder pero en la version que utilizo ya no se usa esa carpeta de startup si no que de genera en programs, por ejemplo en la cookie de autenticacion, para esta uso el siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que lei es que debo hacer algo parecido pero para la claim de role el problema es que no se como, me podrían ayudar

lo estaria usando aca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se supone que el User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role) me deveria devolver el role que tiene el usuario pero me devuelve 0

Comment: 1.- Todas las imágenes debes colocarlas como texto-- 2.- Agrega además el código desde donde llamas a `asignarSesion(`

Comment: ya lo solucione Gracias

Comment: Y cual era el problema?